# Getting wrong python version when trying to install nodejs package with Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, node-modules

In my old meteor version, I was able to install the [swisseph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swisseph) nodeJS package with:

```
npm install swisseph
```

But at that time I had to use

```
var swisseph = Meteor.npmRequire('swisseph');
```

which is from

```
https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm
```

Now I read that Meteorhacks is no longer needed. My problem now is my app depends on using the swisseph NODEjs package but I am now unable to install it.

I get the following errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

swisseph@0.5.7 install /Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/ReactMeteor/react-vedic/node_modules/swisseph
node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! Error: Python executable "/Users/bliss/anaconda/bin/python" is v3.6.1, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR!     at PythonFinder.failPythonVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:492:19)
gyp ERR!     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:474:14)
gyp ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:262:7)
gyp ERR!     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR!     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:897:16)
gyp ERR!     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:340:11) gyp ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
gyp ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
gyp ERR!     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:548:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.1.2/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/ReactMeteor/react-vedic/node_modules/swisseph
gyp ERR! node -v v8.1.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! swisseph@0.5.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the swisseph@0.5.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How do I use this node package even if it is only on the server side?

Comment: From the error it's clear that you have to point it to the correct version of `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

The python version on my computer was higher than the python version needed to install properly. I was able to solve this by explicitly specifying the version of python to be used by `npm install`:

```
npm --python=python2.7 install swisseph
```

Comment: That should be an edit to the question, not the "answer".